# How to increase the max_connections value for MySQL on Windows Server?

Tags: mysql, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2, mysql-5.6, my.cnf

I have an issue with

```
SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections
```

on a Windows Server 2008 r2. Now I'm trying to increase the `max_connections` (the default value is `151`). In the the MySQL `5.6` root folder `D:\...\MySQL5.6` I found a file `my-default.ini` and added

max_connections        = 200

under `[mysqld]`. Then I restarted the service:

[image: Service-Manager-MySQL]

But nothing has changed:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
+-----------------+-------+
¦ Variable_name   ¦ Value ¦
+-----------------+-------+
¦ max_connections ¦ 151   ¦
+-----------------+-------+
```

I renamed the `my-default.ini` to `my.ini` and restarted the MySQL server again. No effect.

**How to set the MySQL `max_connections` permanently on Windows Server?**

Answer (score 1):

My bad -- I edited the wrong `my.ini`.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvCAa2XuQhg) is shown, how to find out, which one is used by the MySQL service on Windows:

1. `[Start]` `->` `Run...` `->` "services.msc"
2. `right click` on the entry of the MySQL service `->` `Properties`
3. `[tab] General`:

[image: MySQL-service-properties]

I updated the proper `my.ini` and restarted the service. Now the new value is being used.